# jsGrid: How to pass additional variables from javascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, jsgrid

[I'm using jsGrid for my project. View here for original source code](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/08/live-table-add-edit-delete-using-php-with-jsgrid-plugin.html)

I want to pass an additional variable call $user_session to use for mysql select query in fetch.php but failed. Below is what i have been trying.

```
<script>

var user_session = "<?php echo $user_session; ?>"; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

//......

 controller: {
  loadData: function(){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "fetch_data.php",
    data: {user_session:user_session} //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   });
  },

 //......
```

Here's the fetch.php file

```
<?php

if($method == 'GET')
{
 $user_session = $_GET['user_session']; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

 $query = "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE first_name=? ORDER BY id DESC";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($user_session); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output[] = array(
   'id'    => $row['id'],   
   'first_name'  => $row['first_name'],
   'last_name'   => $row['last_name'],
   'age'    => $row['age'],
   'gender'   => $row['gender']
  );
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 echo json_encode($output);
}
//......
?>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to do by this way.

```
<script>

//......

 controller: {
  loadData: function(filter){
    var user_session = "<?php echo $user_session; ?>"; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "fetch_data.php",
    data: {filter,
           user_session:user_session //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          },
   });
  },

 //......
</script>
```

In fetch.php i do this.

```
<?php

if($method == 'GET')
{
 $user_session = $_GET['user_session'];//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

 $query = "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE first_name=? ORDER BY id DESC";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute([$user_session]); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output[] = array(
   'id'    => $row['id'],   
   'first_name'  => $row['first_name'],
   'last_name'   => $row['last_name'],
   'age'    => $row['age'],
   'gender'   => $row['gender']
  );
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 echo json_encode($output);
}
//......
?>
```

For the security issue mentioned by @[Andrea Golin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3279175/andrea-golin), i will post another question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, anyone could open up a dev console inside a browser and start fuzzing your session id. While you are correctly preparing your query, defusing sql injection, it does does not protect you from an IDOR, or, i could  enumerate your users by just querying your application repeatedly.

If you really want to pass your session id client-side, maybe you could consider using a cookie, as it is less easily editable by a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a better way.
I can directly call $user_session inside fetch.php.

```
<?php
require('user_session.php'); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
require('includes/db.php');

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == 'GET')
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE first_name=? ORDER BY id DESC";
 $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute([$user_session]); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output[] = array(
   'ChildID'    => $row['ChildID'],
   'Name'  => $row['Name'],
   'BirthDate'   => $row['BirthDate'],
   'Gender'   => $row['Gender'],
   'StudyorWorking'   => $row['StudyorWorking'],
   'CourseorOccupation'   => $row['CourseorOccupation'],
   'Married'   => $row['Married']
  );
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```